# React - Chrome inspector shows element being added / removed but the change isn't visible in the browser itself

Tags: reactjs

New to React, and I'm trying to add a loading indicator based on a state change. I see the loading indicator being added and removed in the Chrome inspector, but it isn't visible in the browser. To make sure it wasn't a CSS issue I reversed the logic - showing the indicator by default and hiding it when loading is occurring - and this causes it to always be visible. Again, I see it appearing and disappearing from the Chrome inspector, just not in the browser. This same method seems to work elsewhere, so I must be missing something.

I also tried adding and removing a CSS class to toggle visibility and I see the same effect - the class is added and removed in the inspector but no change is happening in the browser. Could something be preventing re-render?

I inherited this project so am not completely familiar with the code. Any hints for what I could look for would be much appreciated!

I'm seeing the same behavior in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
render(){

    return (
        {this.state.filtering ? <div className='filter-loading-indicator'><img src={loadingGif} /></div>: null}
    )

}
```

Comment: Him @dm5, in your posted code, there is no redux usage. if you use the redux in this code, please share more about it.

Comment: Removed mention of Redux, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: in this code, there are no bugs, so, I think there are bugs in other code.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: i think you didn't use the `this.setState({...});` function to control the state.

Comment: I'm using this.setState({ filtering: true }) and this.setState({ filtering: false }) when the loading indicator should be shown / hidden.

Comment: Looking at the wrong element in inspected Vs the one in the UI? Otherwise try undefined or false instead of null?

Comment: @JoelHarkes, it's the only element of its kind on the page. I just tried undefined and false instead, but the result is the same. Thanks for your suggestions.